# How do I answer the interviewer why i got terminated for these bad reasons?

Tags: interviewing

I have been terminated from my job previously. Nevertheless, I had moved on and I continue to job hunt.

The reasons for my termination were these offences:

1. 3 consecutive bad performance Quarterly reviews (q1, q2 and q3).
2. Delayed project executions and datelines by (7) weeks.
3. Abusing the office facilities (Internet).

This happened because of my lack of skills in the job I was previously holding.
How can I make these reasons into a positive environment if the interviewer asks me?

Comment: Can you describe things you have learned and changes you have made?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan i have learn about IOT  and mobile app,after that i got switched web development instead under the UI section like html,bootstrap and css

Comment: I think Patricia is getting at what *soft* skills you've learnt, not specific technical skills - how you react to bad feedback, how you keep yourself focussed and motivated, how you seek help when you're stuck, etc. Skills that will prevent the next job going the same way.

Comment: Given the quality of the question, and forgive my bluntness, the errors that exist, I don't believe English is OP's native language. It is difficult to translate and transmit gauge of soft skills (which is primarily verbal) through a foreign language medium.

Comment: @FrankFYC yeah it just slpattered out from my mind thanks anyway

Comment: @JuliaHayward i do not know whether this answer is correct or not ,i will take the bad  feedback as my lesson to be more of a professional person.Something like that ,i am quite nervous because its on monday for my interview to begin

Comment: If you present the reason to a potential employer as you did here, it may sound a bit too clinical. You should show that you understand the reason by summarising it in your own words, not just paraphrase or quote the reason you were given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... those are some serious termination reasons. But your question is still off-topic (ish).

What would you do in this new job to prevent such issues from happening again?

As far as answering, you can state that you fell behind in your projects and missed deadlines. After taking some time to reevaluate what went wrong, you have addressed these shortcomings by [insert your plans here].

Although my personal take is that there is no need to get into detail unless asked. Lying would not get you anywhere (whether or not you get caught, when you get caught it will ruin you), nor would saying things that would put you in a negative light.

I'd focus on stating that you are excited for this new role and would be confident that you would do a good job.

Comment: Difference in that it was the reason that the company decided to terminate, but OP disagreed. Unless OP agrees the reason, wouldn't this be a viable explanation?

Comment: Makes sense Joe, I'll make a quick revision.

Answer (score 4):

> The reasons for my termination were these offences:
>
> - 3 consecutive bad performance Quarterly reviews (q1, q2 and q3).
> - Delayed project executions and datelines by (7) weeks.
> - Abusing the office facilities (Internet).
>
> This happened because of my lack of skills in the job I was previously
>   holding.

Perhaps the first two were due to lack of skill. The third has nothing to do with skill. Perhaps it was just immaturity?

> How can I make these reason into a positive environment if the
>   interviewer asks me?

I don't see any way to turn those into a positive.

Instead, accept that you were rightly terminated for these reasons. Explain the lessons you have learned about yourself and that you now understand what you must do going forward. Talk about what you have changed so that you can assure future employers that you will do better.

Work hard in your job search to find a job where your skills match their needs.

Comment: understood and thanks,but how am i going to explain in a nicer way if that you can help about

Comment: yes ,i admit its my mistake ,its just if they find out from my boss ,its really not going to be a smooth ride ,i just want to convince them.After all to be more a clearer picture there was indeed some internal  problem  with this previous company which i am not satisfied ,i should move on as i said